Create a directory for every new contact in ms-access and check the existence only with the ID of the contact
I would like to create a new directory for any new contact I enter in an access database but I would like to check the existence of the directory only with the last 4 characters. These last 4 characters are the ID of the contact, so in case someone change the details of the contact (like the name) the form will not create a new directory. For this reason with a field "TxtContactAs" I calculate the name of the directory to something like "John Doe - 0085"
My code is:
Private Sub MakeContactFolder()
    
    Dim Path As String
    
    Path = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\" & Me.TxtCustOrSupp.Value
    If Dir(Path, vbDirectory) = vdNullString Then MkDir (Path)
    
    Path = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\" & Me.TxtCustOrSupp.Value & "\" & Me.TxtContactAs.Value
    If Right(Dir(Path, vbDirectory), 4) <> Right(Me.TxtContactAs.Value, 4) Then MkDir (Path)
    
End Sub

The problem is that it doesn't give me an error but every time I change the details of the contact the form creates a new directory with the new name.

The intrinsic constant is vbNullString, not vdNullString. You must not have Option Explicit at top of module which should catch this as an undeclared variable error. However, that will not fix your issue. I would advise not building folder path with names if change of name is a concern. Could replace name part with an * character for the Dir() search.

You are right for the constant, sorry. I copy paste it from my txt editor.
Look, I'm an landscape architect and I'm the only one who uses this database. So, the change of name is not a huge concern but quite often happens to have my customer's name and I open a new project and on the way they decide that they want the customer to be a company they own or the spouse etc...

Why copy/paste from text editor and not from VBA? So did my suggestion help? Alternative is to loop through parent folder and see if any subfolder has the ID in its name - InStr() function could be used for that.

I had already test the code on my database and was working after I found there the mistake and when I sent the message here I copy/paste it from the text editor were for some reason I didn't correct it.
I'm working on your suggestion. I think I will work it out. Check by using a wildcard makes big time sense. When I have some progress I will inform you!

I finally decide to go around this problem. I add a field to the contacts table in which is stored the name of the folder for every new record. This field is not updated when is not null.
